# yocto bitbake 'python3 setup.py bdist_wheel ' execution failed

Tags: python-3.x, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

Im trying to build my own custom image with gstd, however, I'm getting this error:
`'python3 setup.py bdist_wheel ' execution failed.`

Logs:

```
ERROR: gstd-1.0-r0 do_compile: 'python3 setup.py bdist_wheel ' execution failed.
ERROR: gstd-1.0-r0 do_compile: ExecutionError('/home/ubuntu/roby/imx8x-kirkstone/build/tmp/work/armv8a-mx8-poky-linux/gstd/1.0-r0/temp/run.do_compile.3897032', 1, None, None)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/ubuntu/roby/imx8x-kirkstone/build/tmp/work/armv8a-mx8-poky-linux/gstd/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.3897032
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing python function autotools_aclocals
| DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'bit-64', 'arm-common', 'arm-64', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'aarch64-linux', 'common']
| DEBUG: Python function autotools_aclocals finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| /home/ubuntu/roby/imx8x-kirkstone/build/tmp/work/armv8a-mx8-poky-linux/gstd/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python3-native/python3: can't open file '/home/ubuntu/roby/imx8x-kirkstone/build/tmp/work/armv8a-mx8-poky-linux/gstd/1.0-r0/git/setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
| ERROR: 'python3 setup.py bdist_wheel ' execution failed.
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Task (/home/ubuntu/roby/imx8x-kirkstone/build/../layers/meta-myos/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstd.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
```

This is the gstd.bb I'm using: https://github.com/RidgeRun/meta-ridgerun/blob/master/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstd_0.15.0.bb

I'm using kirkstone series for all my BSPs.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using this recipe instead: https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/blob/kirkstone/meta-multimedia/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer-1.0/gstd_git.bb
I'm still not sure whats wrong on the gstd_0.15.0.bb recipe, so I'm still looking forward to the solution if someone knows what can cause this.